# Executable code files randomly disappearing after "Access is denied" error?

Tags: c++

Created a simple code with a class implementation in C++, tried to compile it in Visual Studio Code using G++ with
`g++ testingCPP.cpp -o TEST` and it compiled fine, but on execution I received an error saying "Access is denied." Using cmd I tried compiling with the same name "TEST" and it gave me another error, from what I could find supposedly because of the linker, `cannot open output file TEST.exe: permission denied  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.` Then I tried running the same code in Code::Blocks and that worked, of course since it's different.

For some of the times I tried opening executables, I wouldn't even have permission to, instead a Windows error would appear (paraphrased): `You do not have permission to access this application, path or file. Maybe, you don't have enough privileges to access this object.` Same goes for even if I tried opening it using admin powers. I looked for answers to that, too, and tried going into the executable's properties and giving each user listed full access. Even trying with admin privileges, that failed me too.

As other forum posts hinted, I definitely have changed source code while it was still executing in VS Code. But the weird part is, the executables started **disappearing**. I'd compile in cmd using `g++ testingCPP.cpp -o [newName]` and everytime I try to run it, I get the "Access is denied" error. Then the executable disappears. I turned on the option to see hidden files/folders in Windows 7 and I still can't find any of them. I tried searching for any of them anywhere I can and I've found nothing. If I compile with a name I tried before (including any instance of [newName]) I will get the `collect2.exe: error.`

This is absolutely ridiculous, I've run into problem after problem and I ended up finding no consistent answers for *any* of them. If you can help with this, I'd really appreciate it. There shouldn't be anything wrong with the simple source code, but here it is anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void haltEnd() //For executables to not instantly close
{
  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << flush;
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

class Monkeyz
{
    //Instantiate all variables for no unpredictable behaviour
    string name{};
    int year{};
    bool isBald{};
    public:
    Monkeyz(string n, int y, bool b) : name(n), year(y), isBald(b){}
    int get_year(){return year;}
};

int main()
{
    Monkeyz momo{"Momo", 1964, 0};
    cout << momo.get_year() << endl;
    haltEnd();
}
```

EDIT: For clarification, the only problem is with the initial source file `testingCPP.cpp`, there's no errors if I rewrite the same code in another file. I'm just curious how it messed up THIS bad.

Comment: nine times out of ten these issues are caused by virus scanners.

Comment: It's possible your antivirus software is detecting false-positives and then removing or quarantining the executables. You might try adding an exception or exclusion for the project folder where you are compiling the code.

Comment: Unrelated: The semicolons (`;`) you have after the member functions shouldn't be there. Also, use `name(std::move(n))` since you take the string to the constructor by value,  `get_year()` should be `get_year() const` and use `false` instead of `0`.

Comment: I do have running Bitdefender antivirus. I'll know from now that the semicolons aren't needed @TedLyngmo, but I don't know the std::move semantics to use it with confidence as I'm only around topics relating to the STL.